# How do I merge data working with different excel files in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 different excel files, each one contains different data, one of them 
has the next columns:

```
No. | Name | Xvalue | Yvalue |
```

And the other has the columns:

```
No. | Average | highestvalue | lowerValue
```

I want to merge this data based on the value of the number or the name, in the first excel i can have data from No. 1 to No. 50 but in the second i can have only data for No. 5, 9, 10, 20,

I want to merge my list to fit this data with the first file correspondig to the same value of No. or the same name.

How can i do that? I've tried this:

```
pd.merge(excel1, excel2)
```

But it doesn't fit my data

Comment: Perhaps it would help to go through [some basics.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Also, I think it my prove useful to add some sample data, with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your data is structured however, it seems you want certain attributes form excel2 in excel1.. This will merge on the column specified.

```
excel1.merge(excel2, left_on='No.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead:

```
pd.merge(excel1, excel2, how='outer')
```